# MySQL join tables and pivot (one more)

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have the following WordPress tables:

wp_f7h0p6_users

```
---------------------------------------
| ID | user_login | user_email        |
|  1 |  johnd     | johnd@example.com |
|  2 |  foob      | foob@example.com  |
```

wp_f7h0p6_usermeta

```
------------------------------------------------------
| umeta_id | user_id | meta_key          | meta_value |
|  1       |  1      | first_name        | John       |
|  2       |  1      | last_name         | Doe        |
```

I want to get a SELECT result like this, for which I need to transpose the `wp_f7h0p6_usermeta` table somehow.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| user_login | user_email        | first_name | last_name |
| johnd      | johnd@example.com | John       | Doe       |
| foob       | foob@example.com  | Foo        | Bar       |
```

I tried something like this. But it doesn't group the results into one record per user:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    user_login,
    (CASE M.meta_key WHEN 'first_name' THEN M.meta_value END) first_name,
    (CASE M.meta_key WHEN 'last_name' THEN M.meta_value END) last_name,
    (CASE M.meta_key WHEN 'billing_first_name' THEN M.meta_value END) billing_first_name
    
FROM wp_f7h0p6_users U 
INNER JOIN wp_f7h0p6_usermeta M ON U.ID = M.user_id
```

The result looks like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| user_login | user_email        | first_name | last_name |
| johnd      | johnd@example.com |            |           |
| johnd      |                   | John       |           |
| johnd      |                   |            | Doe       |
```

How can I group those correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a fake aggregation and group  by

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    user_login,
    max((CASE M.meta_key WHEN 'first_name' THEN M.meta_value END) ) first_name,
    max((CASE M.meta_key WHEN 'last_name' THEN M.meta_value END) )last_name,
    max((CASE M.meta_key WHEN 'billing_first_name' THEN M.meta_value END))  billing_first_name
    
    FROM wp_f7h0p6_users U 
    INNER JOIN wp_f7h0p6_usermeta M ON U.ID = M.user_id
    GROUP BY user_login
```

or use  several join for same table using alias

```
SELECT 
user_login,
M1.meta_value first_name,
M2.meta_value last_name,
M3.meta_value  billing_first_name

FROM wp_f7h0p6_users U 
INNER JOIN wp_f7h0p6_usermeta M1 ON U.ID = M1.user_id and  M1.meta_key = 'first_name'
INNER JOIN wp_f7h0p6_usermeta M2 ON U.ID = M2.user_id and  M2.meta_key = 'last_name'
INNER JOIN wp_f7h0p6_usermeta M3 ON U.ID = M3.user_id  and  M3.meta_key = 'billing_first_name'
```

Comment: Thanks! The first solution works wonderfully. (so simple GROUP BY).
But the second one I can't get to work. It gives me a syntax error on `M1.meta_key = 'first_name'`
(plus you have s small error on line 4 where you have two dots instead of one). I'll accept this as solution.

Comment: Wonderful. Second solution works now as well!

Answer (score 1):

One option would be converting to a dynamic pivot in which no need to add the conditional whatever `meta_key` presented ,even if newly inserted, within the table by using

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
             CONCAT(
                    'MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = "', meta_key,'" THEN meta_value END ) AS ',
                    meta_key
                    )
       )
  INTO @sql
  FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT meta_key FROM wp_f7h0p6_usermeta ) AS m;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT user_login,',@sql,
                   ' FROM wp_f7h0p6_users U 
                     JOIN wp_f7h0p6_usermeta M 
                       ON U.ID = M.user_id
                    GROUP BY user_login'); 

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d86e81673cb5b76d6acd74825ffb8a8f)</kbd>